# nginx - 301 redirect /subfolder1/some-friendly-url-12345 to /subfolder2/some-friendly-url

Tags: nginx, rewrite, 301-redirect

I'm a newbie on nginx.

I have some old url's like ***/aaaaa/some-friendly-url-12345*** and I want to 301 redirect these url's to new one but without ID's, like ***/bbbbb/some-friendly-url***.

I also want to redirect ***/aaaaa/*** to ***/bbbbb/***

I tried some *location* directives but I couldn't success somehow.

This is one of I tried:

```
location ~ /aaaaa/(?P<a_slug>.*)$-(?P<a_id>.*) {
   return 301 https://domain.com/bbbbb/$a_slug;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have an embedded `$` in your regular expression which should probably be at the end. See [this document](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) for more on regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the `$` to the end, the regular expression should work for limited cases. It can be improved by making the final term match numerics only (so you are not relying on the greediness of the first capture). For example:

```
location ~ ^/aaaaa/(?<a_slug>.*)-\d+$ {
    return 301 /bbbbb/$a_slug;
}
```

Which can also be rewritten using a `rewrite` expression:

```
rewrite ^/aaaaa/(.*)-\d+$ /bbbbb/$1 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more. Also, [this resource for regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).